# ExpandableListView calls getGroupView always with groupPosition parameter as 0

Tags: android, arraylist, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a dummy JSON data which has an ArrayList with size of 8. They must be populated in the expandableListView, but it shows only the first group. Because when I debug it, getGroupView always is invoked with groupPosition parameter as zero.

There are lots of examples about populating ExpandableListViews with ArrayLists and my code is almost the same with them. But I didn't understand why this happens.

Any help will be much appreciated

My ExpandableListViewApdater:

```
public class ElvProgramCourseListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ProgramOnly programOnly;

public ElvProgramCourseListAdapter(Activity activity, ProgramOnly programOnly) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.programOnly = programOnly;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return programOnly.getProgramSummary().getProgramSetList().size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    NativeProgramSet item = programOnly.getProgramSummary().getProgramSetList().get(groupPosition);
    if (item.getId() != null) {
        return item.getCourseIdList().size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return programOnly.getProgramSummary().getProgramSetList().get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    NativeProgramSet item = programOnly.getProgramSummary().getProgramSetList().get(groupPosition);
    if (item.getId() != null) {
        return item.getCourseIdList().get(childPosition);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imgContentListThumbnail;
    ImageView imgContentListRibbon;
    ImageView imgTLIcon;
    ImageView imgKilitIcon;
    TextView txtContentListTitle;
    TextView txtContentListDescription;
    ImageView imgContentListDetail;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contentlist, parent, false);

        imgContentListThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListThumbnail);
        imgContentListRibbon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListRibbon);
        imgTLIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgTLIcon);
        imgKilitIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgKilitIcon);
        txtContentListTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListTitle);
        Fonts.setTypeface(Fonts.BOLD, txtContentListTitle, activity.getBaseContext());
        txtContentListDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListDescription);
        imgContentListDetail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListDetail);

        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail));
    } else {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        imgContentListThumbnail = viewHolder.imgContentListThumbnail;
        imgContentListRibbon = viewHolder.imgContentListRibbon;
        imgTLIcon = viewHolder.imgTLIcon;
        imgKilitIcon = viewHolder.imgKilitIcon;
        txtContentListTitle = viewHolder.txtContentListTitle;
        txtContentListDescription = viewHolder.txtContentListDescription;
        imgContentListDetail = viewHolder.imgContentListDetail;
    }

    NativeProgramSet nativeProgramSet = (NativeProgramSet) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if(nativeProgramSet.getId() != null) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5e5e5"));
        imgContentListThumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgContentListRibbon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgTLIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imgKilitIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtContentListDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(isExpanded) {
            imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.accordion_close_icon);
        } else {
            imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.accordion_open_icon);
        }

        txtContentListTitle.setText(nativeProgramSet.getName());
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        imgContentListThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtContentListDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_search_filter_button_icon);

        Course course = null;
        for(Course item : programOnly.getProgramSummary().getCourseList()) {
            if(item.getId().equals(nativeProgramSet.getCourseIdList().get(0))) {
                course = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(course != null) {
            convertView = fillListItem(course, imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail, convertView);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imgContentListThumbnail;
    ImageView imgContentListRibbon;
    ImageView imgTLIcon;
    ImageView imgKilitIcon;
    TextView txtContentListTitle;
    TextView txtContentListDescription;
    ImageView imgContentListDetail;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contentlist, parent, false);

        imgContentListThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListThumbnail);
        imgContentListRibbon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListRibbon);
        imgTLIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgTLIcon);
        imgKilitIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgKilitIcon);
        txtContentListTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListTitle);
        Fonts.setTypeface(Fonts.BOLD, txtContentListTitle, activity.getBaseContext());
        txtContentListDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContentListDescription);
        imgContentListDetail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContentListDetail);

        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail));
    } else {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        imgContentListThumbnail = viewHolder.imgContentListThumbnail;
        imgContentListRibbon = viewHolder.imgContentListRibbon;
        imgTLIcon = viewHolder.imgTLIcon;
        imgKilitIcon = viewHolder.imgKilitIcon;
        txtContentListTitle = viewHolder.txtContentListTitle;
        txtContentListDescription = viewHolder.txtContentListDescription;
        imgContentListDetail = viewHolder.imgContentListDetail;
    }

    Long courseId = (Long) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    imgContentListThumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtContentListDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imgContentListDetail.setImageResource(R.drawable.top_search_filter_button_icon);

    Course course = null;
    for(Course item : programOnly.getProgramSummary().getCourseList()) {
        if(item.getId().equals(courseId)) {
            course = item;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(course != null) {
        convertView = fillListItem(course, imgContentListThumbnail, imgContentListRibbon, imgTLIcon, imgKilitIcon, txtContentListTitle, txtContentListDescription, imgContentListDetail, convertView);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public final ImageView imgContentListThumbnail;
    public final ImageView imgContentListRibbon;
    public final ImageView imgTLIcon;
    public final ImageView imgKilitIcon;
    public final TextView txtContentListTitle;
    public final TextView txtContentListDescription;
    public final ImageView imgContentListDetail;

    public ViewHolder(ImageView imgContentListThumbnail, ImageView imgContentListRibbon, ImageView imgTLIcon, ImageView imgKilitIcon, TextView txtContentListTitle, TextView txtContentListDescription, ImageView imgContentListDetail) {
        this.imgContentListThumbnail = imgContentListThumbnail;
        this.imgContentListRibbon = imgContentListRibbon;
        this.imgTLIcon = imgTLIcon;
        this.imgKilitIcon = imgKilitIcon;
        this.txtContentListTitle = txtContentListTitle;
        this.txtContentListDescription = txtContentListDescription;
        this.imgContentListDetail = imgContentListDetail;
    }
}

private View fillListItem(final Course crs, ImageView imgContentListThumbnail, ImageView imgContentListRibbon, ImageView imgTLIcon, ImageView imgKilitIcon, TextView txtContentListTitle, TextView txtContentListDescription, ImageView imgContentListDetail, View convertView) {
   //long stuff
}
}
```

**EDIT**

ProgramOnly.class

```
public class ProgramOnly implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 75459834905648086L;

private String HtmlContent;
private Course currentCourse;
private Program program;
private int videoCount;
private int quizCount;
private int eLearningCount;
private ArrayList<Page> orderedRelatedContent;
private String KALTURA_SESSION_KEY;
private String KALTURA_PREVIEW_SESSION_KEY;
private String videoId;
private boolean isPublicAccess;
private ArrayList<Document> contentDocuments;
private CourseStatusMap courseStatusMap;
private CertificateStatusMap certificateStatus;
private String programAttendeeId;
private String attendeeId;

private int pdfCount;
private int pptCount;
private int htmlCount;
private int audioCount;
private int interval;
private ProgramStatus contentStatus;

private String urlForSocialSharing;

private boolean isContentMustBePurchased;

public Program getProgramSummary() {
    return program;
}

//getter setter stuff
```

Comment: is `ProgramOnly` is a custom class by you? Then please post the class code.

Comment: I think Rivu is on the right track. In the getGroupView you ask for programOnly.size() which leads me to believe theres something in there.

Comment: It is a huge custom class which incluıdes many custom classes by me as well. As you can see I access ProgramSummary class object then get the ProgramSetList array to populate it. Do you still want the class code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Android is not as clever as I expected. My `ExpandableListView` is in a `ScrollView` and that makes its height always the same with one item. What a bug!

So I hack Android by measuring total height at just after setting adapter and  `onGroupExpand` and `onGroupCollapse`

Setting Adapter:

```
ExpandableListView elvProgramCourseList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvProgramCourseList);
ElvProgramCourseListAdapter adapter = new ElvProgramCourseListAdapter(this, programOnly);
elvProgramCourseList.setGroupIndicator(null);
elvProgramCourseList.setChildIndicator(null);
elvProgramCourseList.setAdapter(adapter);
setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(elvProgramCourseList, null);
```

`onGroupExpand`:

```
elvProgramCourseList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        ExpandableListView elvProgramCourseList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvProgramCourseList);
        collapseOtherGroups(elvProgramCourseList, groupPosition);
        setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(elvProgramCourseList, groupPosition);
    }
});
```

`onGroupCollapse`:

```
elvProgramCourseList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvProgramCourseList);
        ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter = expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter();

        if (expandableListAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }

        boolean areAllGroupsCollapsed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < expandableListAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            if(expandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                areAllGroupsCollapsed = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(areAllGroupsCollapsed) {
            setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(expandableListView, null);
        }
    }
});
```

Measuring the total height:

```
private void setExpandableListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ExpandableListView expandableListView, Integer expandedGroupPosition) {
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter = expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter();

    if (expandableListAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int totalDividerHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < expandableListAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        View groupItem = expandableListAdapter.getGroupView(i, expandedGroupPosition != null, null, expandableListView);
        totalHeight += Utils.convertDpToPixel(92.42f, this);

        if(expandedGroupPosition != null && expandedGroupPosition.equals(i)) {
            for(int j=0;j<expandableListAdapter.getChildrenCount(i);j++) {
                View childItem = expandableListAdapter.getChildView(i, j, j+1==expandableListAdapter.getChildrenCount(i), null, expandableListView);
                totalHeight += Utils.convertDpToPixel(92.42f, this);
            }
            totalDividerHeight += expandableListView.getDividerHeight() * (expandableListAdapter.getChildrenCount(i)-1);
        }
    }

    totalDividerHeight += expandableListView.getDividerHeight() * (expandableListAdapter.getGroupCount()-1);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = expandableListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + totalDividerHeight;
    expandableListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    expandableListView.requestLayout();
}
```

Android, you did made me lost a lot of time. GRRRRRR!

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution in a tutorial:

```
public class SecondLevelExpanableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public SecondLevelExpanableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

this worked for me!